# Resampling with pandas.MultiIndex: Resampler.aggregate() & Resampler[column]

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I am trying to resample a data frame. First, I want to keep several aggregations in the result. Second, there is an additional aggregation in interest for a specific column. Since this aggregation is only relevant to a single column, the resampler can be limited to this column in order not to unnecessarily apply the aggregation to the other columns.

This scenario is working for a simple one-dimensional column index:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(50,4), index=pd.to_datetime(np.arange(0, 50), unit="s"), columns=["a", "b", "c", "d"])
r = df.resample("10s")
result = r.aggregate(["mean", "std"])
result[("d", "ffill")] = r["d"].ffill()
print(result)
```

However, as soon as I start to use multi-indexed columns problems appear. First, I can not keep several aggregations at once:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([("a", "b"), ("alpha", "beta")])
r = df.resample("10s")    # can be omitted
result = r.aggregate(["mean", "std"])
---> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Second, the resampler can not be limited to the relevant column anymore:

```
r[("b", "beta")].ffill()
--> KeyError: "Columns not found: 'b', 'beta'"
```

How can I transform my concern from simple indices to multi-indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) in a `groupby` instead of resample, such as:

```
result = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10s',level=0)).aggregate(["mean", "std"])
print (result)
                           a                                       b  \
                        alpha                beta               alpha   
                         mean       std      mean       std      mean   
1970-01-01 00:00:00  0.460569  0.312508  0.476511  0.260534  0.479577   
1970-01-01 00:00:10  0.441498  0.315277  0.487855  0.306068  0.535842   
1970-01-01 00:00:20  0.569884  0.248503  0.320552  0.288479  0.507755   
1970-01-01 00:00:30  0.478037  0.262654  0.552214  0.251581  0.505132   
1970-01-01 00:00:40  0.611227  0.328916  0.473773  0.241604  0.358298   


                                   beta            
                          std      mean       std  
1970-01-01 00:00:00  0.357493  0.448487  0.294432  
1970-01-01 00:00:10  0.259145  0.472250  0.320954  
1970-01-01 00:00:20  0.369490  0.432944  0.150473  
1970-01-01 00:00:30  0.298759  0.381614  0.248785  
1970-01-01 00:00:40  0.203831  0.381412  0.374965
```

and for the second part, I'm not sure what you mean, but according to the result given in the case of the single column level, try this it gives a result

```
result[("b", "beta",'ffill')] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10s',level=0))[[("b", "beta")]].first()
```

Comment: First, using `groupby` with `pd.Grouper` solves the issue with `aggregate`. That it is not working with `resample` seems really to be bug as *Quang Hoang* has mentioned.
Second, it is important to **not** re-execute the "compute-intensive" grouping. However, encapsulating the multi-index tuple in a list while re-using the `DataFrameGroupBy` object does the trick: `r[[("b", "beta")]].first()`. BTW, `first()` is the more appropriate operation. Thank you!

Comment: @Chickenmarkus indeed twice `groupby` is not the best, but I assumed you would create it before like you did with your `r`. Your second remark made me think that in the case of the Multiindex, with `r = df.resample("10s")`, if you do `r[df.columns].aggregate(["mean", "std"])` it actually works as expected :)

Answer (score 3):

It must be a bug in `aggregate`. A go-around would be `stack`:

```
(df.stack().groupby(level=-1)
  .apply(lambda x:x.resample('10s', level=0).aggregate(["mean", "std"]))
  .unstack(level=0)
)
```

Comment: Has anyone reported this bug to Pandas?  I'm still getting it in version 1.5.2.  Looks like this issue is related: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/29919#issue-530050472

Comment: I updated my pandas to 2.0.3 and the issue seems to be fixed!